# Docker-compose: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, kafka-consumer-api

I use **fastapi**, **docker**, **docker-compose**, **kafka**.
I try to up the **modules-consumer**:

```
docker-compose up consumer-modules
```

But I received **ModuleNotFoundError**:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

Import in **modules_consumer.py**:

```
from core import settings
```

where `core` - project folder, not library.

**Dockerfile**:

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN rm -rf .venv/
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y locales \
    python-dev-is-python3 libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libssl-dev \
    libmagic1 && \
    echo ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8 >> /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen && \
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python -m pip install poetry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install --no-root --no-dev

EXPOSE 80
```

**Consumer-modules** in **docker-compose.yaml**:

```
consumer-modules:
    build:
      context: ../app
    volumes:
      - ../app:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: sh -c "python3 consumers/modules_consumer.py"
```

Project structure:

```
app/
├─ consumers/
│  ├─ modules_consumer.py
│  ├─ __init__.py
├─ core/
│  ├─ settings.py
│  ├─ __init__.py
├─ Dockerfile
├─ docker-compose.yaml
```

I found issues with a similar problem on **stackoverflow** but they did not help me.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Don't use images of text, use text. Also, extract a [mcve]. Lastly, have you searched for the error message?

Comment: Thank you for advice. I fixed the description. Yes, of course, I searched.

Comment: Can you add the file structure that you have inside your container? You're doing `COPY .  /app` so we can't see how `consumers/modules_consumer.py` relates to `core.py`. The short answer to your question is going to be 'the `core.py` file isn't included in your path at the point when `modules_consumer.py` runs inside the container.

Comment: @Paddy Alton Thank you for your answer. But I don't have such file ```core.py```. It's folder (I mentioned it in the description).

Comment: hello @sergey, can you add this file `core/__init__.py` and execute your `build` & `run` compose commands once again?

Comment: @Franco Gil Hello. Yes, I have ```core/__init__.py```. And I tried ```docker-compose up --build consumer-modules```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a path issue. It's best resolved by modifying the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable, which tells the Python process where to find files it requires.

### The problem

You have explained that the directory structure is

```
/app
├─ core/
│  ├─ settings.py
├─ consumers/
│  ├─ modules_consumer.py
```

When you run `docker compose up`, the `consumer-modules` service is configured to run the command `python3 consumers/modules_consumer.py`. This runs inside the container in `/app`.

Now, what happens is this: the code in `modules_consumer.py` executes from the subdirectory in which the file is located. If it were located at `/app/modules_consumer.py`, the code it contains - `from core import settings` - would run just fine. The Python process would look in all the immediate subdirectories (`core/` and `consumers/`) for `settings.py` and would find it in `core/`.

By contrast, because `modules_consumer.py` is in `consumers/`, this cannot happen (without help). After failing to find a file called `core.py` in `consumers/`, the Python process is going to look for any subdirectories in `consumers/` and won't find any.

### The solution

The way to resolve this is to add `/app` to the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable. This way, the Python process will know that - *as well as* the current directory - it should look for imports in `/app`.

I think in your case the simplest thing to do is to overwrite this variable in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
consumer-modules:
    build:
      context: ../app
    volumes:
      - ../app:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - PYTHONPATH=/app
    command: sh -c "python3 consumers/modules_consumer.py"
```

(if it turns out to be more complicated, e.g. because this overwrites some things that are needed and already in the `$PYTHONPATH` by default, there are many alternative ways to set and/or extend this environment variable)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it did not help me. The same error.

Comment: Path issues can sometimes be a little tricky to resolve. I suggest you try to shell in to your `consumer-modules` container (something like `docker run -it <container-name> /bin/bash` usually works) and diagnose from there. e.g. `echo $PYTHONPATH` will show you whether `/app` is indeed included - if it is, you could try adding `core/__init__.py` again, and if not find a different way to set `$PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: container ```consumer_modules``` is not running - I get the error (```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'```) trying to run it . That's why I cann't shell in to it. And, yes, I have ```__init__.py``` file - I fixed project structure.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is correct. But it works for me without double quotes around ```/app``` ===>>> ```PYTHONPATH=/app```.

Comment: Great! I have edited the answer to reflect that.